# Not able to disable the cups service using boot-up manager

Tags: printing, 14.04, boot

In the [bootup-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/bum/), I have disabled cups because I don't have any printers connected to my laptop. But, still the cups service gets automatically started. How to disable such services? BTW, I am using 14.04.

[image]

I changed the permission of the /etc/init.d/cups* files to 000 and still on reboot I see the services when I run the `ps -aef | grep -i cups` command.

```
praveensripati@MyUbuntuLaptop:/etc/init.d$ ls -ltr cups*
---------- 1 root root 3184 Apr  3 22:19 cups
---------- 1 root root 1961 Apr  7 21:04 cups-browsed

praveensripati@MyUbuntuLaptop:/etc/init.d$ ps -aef | grep -i cups
root      1154     1  0 18:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
root      3083     1  0 18:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -f
lp        3087  3083  0 18:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
lp        3088  3083  0 18:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
lp        3089  3083  0 18:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
lp        3090  3083  0 18:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
lp        3091  3083  0 18:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
praveen+  3466  3129  0 18:33 pts/14   00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i cups
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the `cups` service via upstart, try running the following *as* root:

```
echo "manual" > /etc/init/cups.override
```

You can become root by running: `sudo -s` or `su`

#### Taken from the [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#manual)

This stanza will tell Upstart to ignore the start on / stop on stanzas. It is useful for keeping the logic and capability of a job on the system while not having it automatically start at boot-up.

Example:

```
manual
```

Comment: Looks like bum is not UI for upstart, but is picking up the upstart service status.