# Primary partition takes a lot of space

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, disk-usage, disk-management

I am facing a serious problem, unknown files are getting loaded into my primary partition drive and within minutes of logging in , the space extends from 15 GB with 71 GB free space to 40 GB with 46 GB free space, in 30 minutes or so, the entire space in Primary partition becomes full.

I have done everything , deleted CUPS using

```
sudo rm -vfr /var/log && sudo mkdir /var/log
```

Removed cache files and Temp files , but still the system loads every single time

I do not know which files are consuming too much space as disk usage analyzer as i am getting following error

```
Could not scan folder "/" or some of the folders it contains.
```

Kindly let me know how should i check the file which consumes too much space in few minutes.

```
Following is the output when i have run sudo du -sh /*

dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/$ sudo du -sh /*
[sudo] password for  dev: 
9,7M    /bin
67M /boot
4,0K    /cdrom
4,0K    /dev
13M /etc
1,1G    /home
0   /initrd.img
0   /initrd.img.old
525M    /lib
4,0K    /lib64
16K /lost+found
203G    /media
4,0K    /mnt
136M    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2122/task/2122/fd/17’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2122/task/2122/fd/19’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2122/map_files/7f8dec2d0000-7f8dec2d1000’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4143/task/4143/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4143/task/4143/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4143/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4143/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
416K    /root
du: cannot access ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
1,4M    /run
12M /sbin
4,0K    /srv
0   /sys
16K /tmp
13G /usr
455M    /var
0   /vmlinuz
0   /vmlinuz.old
 dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/$
```

I have also ran my entire system to find the files larger than 100 MB

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/$ sudo find / -type f -size +100M -exec du -sh {} + | sort --human-numeric-sort
find: `/proc/2122/task/2122/fd/17': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/2122/fd/17': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/2122/fd/19': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/4256/task/4256/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/4256/task/4256/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/4256/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/4256/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
0   /proc/kcore
101M    /media/dev/Daten/R2015a-glnxa64/archives/common/comm_demos_common_1423523267.enc
103M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Subject/mgh_1010/T1w/xfms/OrigT1w2T1w.nii.gz
104M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/KJNT/24349.da_20150715_081251.PRISMA/nifti/20150715_081251ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
104M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/MANT/25390.3d_20150608_092057.PRISMA/nifti/20150608_092057ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
104M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/MANT/25390.3d_20150609_092242.PRISMA/nifti/20150609_092242ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
105M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/KJNT/24349.da_20150714_073407.PRISMA/nifti/20150714_073407ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
105M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/WRET/26154.57_20150609_072926.PRISMA/nifti/20150609_072926ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
106M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/AP4T/26153.41_20150707_085718.PRISMA/nifti/20150707_085718ep2dDTI20Chp2monos010a001.nii.gz
106M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/BI3T/18080.2d_20150615.PRISMA/nifti/20150615_073354ep2dDTI20Chp2monos009a001.nii.gz
106M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/BI3T/18080.2d_20150616.PRISMA/nifti/20150616_071319ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
106M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/GCLT/27694.69_20150714_124025.PRISMA/nifti/20150714_124025ep2dDTI20Chp2monos010a001.nii.gz
106M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/GCLT/27694.69_20150715_115353.PRISMA/nifti/20150715_115353ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
106M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/PP2T/15339.f9_20150714_102719.PRISMA/nifti/20150714_102719ep2dDTI20Chp2monos013a001.nii.gz
106M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/PP2T/15339.f9_20150715_102331.PRISMA/nifti/20150715_102331ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
107M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/HCBT/08950.3f_20150706_074110.PRISMA/nifti/20150706_074110ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
108M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/AP4T/26153.41_20150706_090720.PRISMA/nifti/20150706_090720ep2dDTI20Chp2monos015a001.nii.gz
108M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/HA5T/08940.88_20150615.PRISMA/nifti/20150615_090918ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
108M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/HA5T/08940.88_20150616.PRISMA/nifti/20150616_090631ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
108M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/HCBT/08950.3f_20150707_080050.PRISMA/nifti/20150707_080050ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
108M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/WRET/26154.57_20150608_074109.PRISMA/nifti/20150608_074109ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
108M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/WW2T/15201.23_20150616.PRISMA/nifti/20150616_104248ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
109M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/RMAT/07707.3c_20150714_085715.PRISMA/nifti/20150714_085715ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
109M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/RMAT/07707.3c_20150715_090704.PRISMA/nifti/20150715_090704ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
109M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/WW2T/15201.23_20150615.PRISMA/nifti/20150615_102106ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
109M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Google Drive/peehs/software/endnote/EndNoteX6.0.2.dmg
110M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/HF9T/24014.f0_20150608_110327.PRISMA/nifti/20150608_110327ep2dDTI20Chp2monos009a001.nii.gz
110M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/HF9T/24014.f0_20150609_103148.PRISMA/nifti/20150609_103148ep2dDTI20Chp2monos008a001.nii.gz
110M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Google Drive/peehs/basics/literatur/mecum/MLP_Duale_Reihe_-_Innere_Medizin__2nd_ed.2009.pdf
111M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Subject/mgh_1010/T1w/xfms/OrigT2w2T1w.nii.gz
112M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms79/DTI/data.nii.gz
112M    /media/dev/Daten/fix1.06/training_files/WhII_Standard.RData
115M    /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/icon-theme.cache
116M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103d/DTI/data.nii.gz
116M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms3/DTI/data.nii.gz
116M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms72b/DTI/data.nii.gz
118M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms16/DTI/data.nii.gz
119M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103c/DTI/data.nii.gz
119M    /media/dev/Daten/R2015a-glnxa64/archives/glnxa64/3p/cuda_glnxa64_1419893829.enc
120M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103a/DTI/data.nii.gz
120M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms30/DTI/data.nii.gz
121M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms54/DTI/data.nii.gz
121M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms59/DTI/data.nii.gz
121M    /media/dev/Programme/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Setup Files/{AC76BA86-7AD7-1031-7B44-AA1000000001}/Data1.cab
123M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms123/DTI/data.nii.gz
123M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms129a/DTI/data.nii.gz
123M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms25a/DTI/data.nii.gz
123M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms79/DTI/79_20130425_DTI.nii.gz
123M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms90/DTI/data.nii.gz
123M    /media/dev/Programme/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/SetupCache/v4.5.51209/NetFx_Full_GDR.mzz
123M    /media/dev/Programme/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/SetupCache/v4.5.51209/NetFx_Full_LDR.mzz
124M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms36/DTI/data.nii.gz
124M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms72b/DTI/72_20120821_DTI.nii.gz
125M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103b/DTI/data.nii.gz
125M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103d/DTI/103_20130221_DTI.nii.gz
125M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms16/DTI/16_20121205_DTI.nii.gz
125M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms3/DTI/3_20121010_DTI.nii.gz
125M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms69/DTI/data.nii.gz
125M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms72a/DTI/72_20120222_DTI.nii.gz
127M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103c/DTI/103_20121116_DTI.nii.gz
127M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms44/DTI/44_20130507_DTI.nii.gz
127M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms59/DTI/59_20120726_DTI.nii.gz
127M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms76a/DTI/data.nii.gz
127M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Subject/mgh_1010/T1w/xfms/OrigT1w2standard.nii.gz
128M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms152b/DTI/152_20140410_DTI.nii.gz
128M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms54/DTI/54_20130418_DTI.nii.gz
129M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103a/DTI/103_20120215_DTI.nii.gz
129M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms129a/DTI/129_20120912_DTI.nii.gz
129M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms152a/DTI/152_20130314_DTI.nii.gz
129M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms90/DTI/90_20120504_DTI.nii.gz
130M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Subject/mgh_1010/T1w/xfms/OrigT2w2standard.nii.gz
131M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms113/DTI/113_20130416_DTI.nii.gz
131M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms25a/DTI/25_20130227_DTI.nii.gz
131M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms36/DTI/36_20120224_DTI.nii.gz
132M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms103b/DTI/103_20120914_DTI.nii.gz
132M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms123/DTI/123_20120316_DTI.nii.gz
132M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms30/DTI/30_20120615_DTI.nii.gz
132M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms69/DTI/69_20120725_DTI.nii.gz
134M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms76a/DTI/76_20130423_DTI.nii.gz
138M    /media/dev/Programme/Windows/System32/MRT.exe
143M    /media/dev/Programme/MSOCache/All Users/{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C/ProPsWW.cab
144M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms106/DTI/data.nii.gz
147M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR_Atlas.dtseries.nii
147M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL_Atlas.dtseries.nii
147M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/T1w/xfms/OrigT1w2T1w.nii.gz
151M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/T1w/xfms/T2w_reg_dc.nii.gz
152M    /media/dev/Daten/DTI_fMRI_Data/bedpostX_MS/subj_ms106/DTI/106_20130319_DTI.nii.gz
154M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Google Drive/peehs/basics/literatur/anatomie/Duvernoy’s+Atlas+of+the+Human+Brain+Stem.pdf
158M    /media/dev/Programme/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/49.0.2623.110/Installer/chrome.7z
159M    /media/dev/Daten/fix1.06/training_files/UKBiobank.RData
160M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir80_LR_gdc.nii.gz
161M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir81_LR_gdc.nii.gz
162M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/T1w/xfms/OrigT2w2T1w.nii.gz
163M    /media/dev/Programme/Recovery/ef125c84-603a-11e5-a18e-bc305b9ebb57/Winre.wim
169M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir80_LR.nii.gz
169M    /media/dev/Programme/ProgramData/Microsoft/Search/Data/Applications/Windows/Windows.edb
170M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir81_LR.nii.gz
170M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Google Drive/peehs/software/endnote/endnoteX5.dmg
181M    /media/dev/Programme/Windows/winsxs/ManifestCache/702349c5b78f9a04_blobs.bin
184M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_RL/DistortionCorrectionAndEPIToT1wReg_FLIRTBBRAndFreeSurferBBRbased/Scout_gdc_undistorted_warp.nii.gz
185M    /media/dev/Daten/fix1.06/training_files/WhII_MB6.RData
185M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_RL/DistortionCorrectionAndEPIToT1wReg_FLIRTBBRAndFreeSurferBBRbased/fMRI2str.nii.gz
185M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/T1w/xfms/rfMRI_REST2_RL2str.nii.gz
188M    /media/dev/Daten/MPICBS/AP4T/26153.41_20150706_090720.PRISMA/nifti/20150706_090720ep2dDTI20Chp2monos015a001.nii
189M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_LR/DistortionCorrectionAndEPIToT1wReg_FLIRTBBRAndFreeSurferBBRbased/fMRI2str.nii.gz
189M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/T1w/xfms/rfMRI_REST2_LR2str.nii.gz
189M    /media/dev/Programme/MSOCache/All Users/{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}-C/ProPsWW2.cab
191M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_LR/DistortionCorrectionAndEPIToT1wReg_FLIRTBBRAndFreeSurferBBRbased/Scout_gdc_undistorted_warp.nii.gz
193M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/T1w/xfms/OrigT1w2standard.nii.gz
193M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/T1w/xfms/OrigT2w2standard.nii.gz
195M    /media/dev/Daten/fix1.06/training_files/Standard.RData
198M    /media/dev/Daten/Pipelines-3.14.1.zip
206M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/Diffusion/rawdata/RL_1.nii.gz
206M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir80_RL.nii.gz
208M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir81_RL.nii.gz
216M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/LS5040_3T_LS_Structural_unproc.zip
222M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/Diffusion/rawdata/LR_1.nii.gz
226M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/Diffusion/rawdata/LR_2.nii.gz
226M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR.L.native.func.gii
226M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL.L.native.func.gii
230M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/Diffusion/rawdata/RL_2.nii.gz
231M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR.R.native.func.gii
232M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL.R.native.func.gii
253M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Google Drive/peehs/basics/literatur/anatomie/Atlas of Human Brain Connections - Marco Catani.pdf
264M    /media/dev/Daten/R2015a-glnxa64/archives/common/symbolic_doc_en_common_1422574394.enc
292M    /media/dev/Daten/fix1.06/compiled/Darwin/x86_64/MCRInstaller.zip
334M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR.nii.gz
334M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/MNINonLinear/Results/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL.nii.gz
334M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR_nonlin_norm.nii.gz
334M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL_nonlin_norm.nii.gz
354M    /home/dev/Downloads/fieldtrip-r10442.zip
354M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Google Drive/peehs/basics/literatur/mecum/Karow, Lang (2006) Pharmakologie und Toxikologie_OCR_Seiten noch überprüfen.pdf
395M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/rfMRI_REST2_RL/LS5040_3T_rfMRI_REST2_RL_gdc.nii.gz
396M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/rfMRI_REST2_LR/LS5040_3T_rfMRI_REST2_LR_gdc.nii.gz
402M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir80_RL_gdc.nii.gz
406M    /media/dev/Programme/Windows/Installer/6c34e.msp
407M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/Diffusion/LS5040_3T_DWI_dir81_RL_gdc.nii.gz
412M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR_mc.nii.gz
412M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL_mc.nii.gz
415M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR_gdc.nii.gz
415M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR_orig.nii.gz
415M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL_gdc.nii.gz
415M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL_orig.nii.gz
415M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/rfMRI_REST2_LR/LS5040_3T_rfMRI_REST2_LR.nii.gz
415M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/unprocessed/3T/rfMRI_REST2_RL/LS5040_3T_rfMRI_REST2_RL.nii.gz
455M    /media/dev/Programme/Temp/SPSS_Statistics_V23 für Windows7/SPSS_Statistics_V23/Bas.cab
511M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_LR/rfMRI_REST2_LR_nonlin.nii.gz
511M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/rfMRI_REST2_RL/rfMRI_REST2_RL_nonlin.nii.gz
572M    /media/dev/Daten/fix1.06/compiled/Linux/x86_64/MCRInstaller.zip
698M    /media/dev/Programme/System Volume Information/{2a6a4683-eebf-11e5-b587-bc305b9ebb57}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
740M    /media/dev/Daten/R2015a-glnxa64/archives/glnxa64/mcr_install_glnxa64_1423802574.enc
786M    /media/dev/Daten/fix1.06/training_files/HCP_hp2000.RData
816M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/LS5040_3T_LS_tfMRI_EMOTION_unproc.zip
864M    /media/dev/Programme/System Volume Information/{8c30e78c-eed5-11e5-bca6-bc305b9ebb57}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
874M    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/Diffusion/eddy/Pos_Neg.nii.gz
878M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Downloads/documents-export-2015-12-09 (3).zip
878M    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Downloads/documents-export-2015-12-09 (4).zip
904M    /media/dev/Daten/R2015a-glnxa64/archives/common/vision_common_1423523243.enc
1020M   /media/dev/Programme/Users/dev/Desktop/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso
1,1G    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/LS5040_3T_LS_tfMRI_GAMBLING_unproc.zip
1,1G    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/LS5040_3T_LS_tfMRI_SOCIAL_unproc.zip
1,1G    /media/dev/Programme/System Volume Information/{9178901f-cc0b-11e5-9386-bc305b9ebb57}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
1,1G    /media/dev/Programme/Windows/SoftwareDistribution/DataStore/DataStore.edb
1,2G    /media/dev/Programme/System Volume Information/{998ba904-eeb8-11e5-9e88-bc305b9ebb57}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
1,5G    /media/dev/Programme/System Volume Information/{32703a79-b546-11e5-815b-bc305b9ebb57}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
1,6G    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/LS5040_3T_LS_tfMRI_WM_unproc.zip
1,7G    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/LS5040_3T_LS_rfMRI_REST3_unproc.zip
1,7G    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Lifespan/LS5040/LS5040_3T_LS_rfMRI_REST4_unproc.zip
1,9G    /media/dev/Programme/System Volume Information/{c05fc5af-b60b-11e5-9508-bc305b9ebb57}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
1,9G    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Downloads/documents-export-2015-12-09 (1).zip
2,1G    /media/dev/Programme/Users/qi shang/Downloads/documents-export-2015-12-09 (2).zip
2,3G    /media/dev/Daten/fix.tar.gz
3,0G    /media/dev/Programme/hiberfil.sys
3,3G    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Subject/mgh_1010/diff/rawdata/mri/diff.nii.gz
3,3G    /media/dev/Programme/System Volume Information/{1409ceeb-b609-11e5-a65a-bc305b9ebb57}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
3,6G    /media/dev/Daten/HCP_Subject/mgh_1010/diff/preproc/mri/diff_preproc.nii.gz
3,9G    /media/dev/Programme/pagefile.sys
7,0G    /media/dev/Daten/Mathworks_Matlab_R2015a_Linux/R2015a-glnxa64.iso
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:/$
```

Following files are being written currently on my computer and i am not aware how they are being written

```
2225 be/4 dev   0.00 B   1260.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [DOM Worker]    2122 be/4 root      0.00 B   2.5     G   0.00 %  0.17 % cupsd -f, 2215 be/4 dev                 0.00 B   1164.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [~torage #1],  165 be/3 root       0.00 B    648.00 K  0.00 %  0.59 % [jbd2/sda8-8]
```

Comment: The command you've posted is just deleting the whole directory containing your logs, which can be very useful in finding out what problems with your system are. I doubt that is useful in your situation. When you're using the command line `sudo du -sh /*` will give you a view on which directory is filling up. Use it once, wait a couple of minutes then try again, and you should be able to compare which has grown.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all files sorted with size

```
sudo find / -type f -exec du -h {} + | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

or show only files bigger than e.g. 100 MB

```
sudo find / -type f -size +100M -exec du -h {} + | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

---

You can monitor disk activity with `iotop`

```
sudo apt-get install iotop
```

then run it

```
sudo iotop -ao
```

and check disk write column (you can navigate using left-right arrows). It will tell you what is writing to disk

Comment: Dear, I have checked it , following files are getting written on my computer     : 2225 be/4 dev       0.00 B   1260.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [DOM Worker] :  2122 be/4 root          0.00 B   1165.86 M  0.00 %  0.17 % cupsd -f, 2215 be/4 dev       0.00 B   1164.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox [~torage #1],  165 be/3 root          0.00 B    648.00 K  0.00 %  0.59 % [jbd2/sda8-8]

Comment: I have checked it, its firefox,CUPSD -f , they are taking more than enough space now in the system

Comment: How to delete CUPSD -f library permanently, kindly please let me know

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have ?

Comment: 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451883/not-able-to-disable-the-cups-service-using-boot-up-manager